# How can I create Textured Outlines?

Tags: texturing

I am working on a model that is a 2D to 3D remake and I'm almost done. I just need to get the outline in. I want it to turn in space so I didn't draw it into the texture.

Most outline solutions I have found don't work with what I am going for. Does anyone know how I can get a textured outline like the one in the reference?

Original by crayonchewer: https://twitter.com/crayonchewer?lang=en

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a few options.

Freestyle creates a line around the edge of all your objects soon render. You may be able to tweak the settings to create the chalk like effect.

Grease pencil is also another option. Can be harder to accomplish but you have more control over the lines.

The last option I have is to use a flat plane and tweak texture settings with clouds to create a brush like stroke. Again, difficult and a hassle but could produce some great effects.

If you want any help on how these may be completed I will try and help where I can.

Torus Test:

[image: Torus-Outline]

EDIT:

This is how I created the torus effect above as requested.

Firstly, create a copy of your item slightly larger than your original. The gap between the two will determine the size of your outline.

Create a circle with the triangle fan fill. The number of vertices is your choice, the higher the count, the better the effect will be but performance will be reduced later. I used 128 for mine.

Go to edit mode.

Select the edge ring and delete all the edges, leaving lines spraying from the centre vertex.

Select everything and extrude to create a pretty cool looking mesh.

Select the centre edge (Done by selecting the two centre vertices) and go to Edge-->Edge Split.

[image: Select these verticies]

Go back to Object mode

This is where thing may get slow for a bit!!

Add a Solidify modifier and set the thickness really low. I set mine to 0.001.

Add a boolean modifier set to intersect. Choose your slightly larger, copied object for the boolean modifier object. Hide your copy object

Now you should see lots of thin lines around the outside of your mesh as shown below. note as they rotate around they get thinner and disappear.

[image: Demonstration of result]

On my torus, I did not need to do this step for this rotation, but if the centre vertex is showing all clustered together on your meshes surface like below, add a subsurf modifier to the top of your modifiers and set it to 1. this should leave a bit of a hole where the vertex was. BUT DONT WORRY!!! we will fix that soon.

More LAG Ahead!!!

Copy your outline object and duplicate it. Rotate it 90˚ on one of the other two axis' so the lines face in a different direction. Note the small hole on the righthand side due to the subsurf modifier. This will be better hidden with the textures. I do have a small glitch (The plane protruding from my mesh) but it is almost unrecognisable in the render. plus you can delete it once modifiers are applied.

[image: Outline BiDirectional]

Hide both of these outlines for now if lag is getting the better of your machine :D

Time for a material. I have taken an image of mine below. if you wanted you could use a texture, but I have gone for a procedural noise texture.

[image: Texture Nodes]

Show your two items again and apply the material. Take a look around in render view. My nodes are set for cycles, so some tweaking may be needed to use in EEVEE.

If you are happy with the results, apply your modifiers IN ORDER!!! and you will get your results in mesh!!

This works by the layering of faces adding their translucency to each other slowly darkening the view. The more layers overlapping, the darker the edge. This does create a little bit of darkening towards the center but when set low like mine it is relitively unoticable.

TADA!

Note that I did this on an early 2015 MacBook air which has relatively low computing power compared to many 3D designers laptops and common desktop PC's. My computer started running quite slow when using the boolean modifier caping my limitations but you may be able to take the number of verticies up in your model.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped.

BFB

Comment: The only problem I have with freestyle and grease pencil is I wanted to upload it to sketch fab for people to spin it around, and those two options are good for renders but not exporting the actual finished model

What did you mean by use a flat plane? Like a flat sprite next to the main  model?

Did you mean something like this where you stick a plane onto the main mesh?
https://i.imgur.com/JWjjx8U.png

That could be interesting

Comment: Do you understand how volumetrics in ever work? It is lots of planes with a texture on it close together. If you create many planes the shape of the model facing at differing rotations, it will look like it is outlined. I will update my answer with an example

Comment: Oh are you talking about the inverted mesh trick? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37j51GY4Fgg

Comment: No but that could work too.

Comment: Whats the method you were you talking about? Ive never heard of that ill try both.

Comment: Hmm. I have never actually done it before so I tried it and it gave me an ok result, but it didn't seem to work so well on more complex meshes. I will put an image on this post of the test i did on a torus.

Comment: It looks good but how did you do that?

Comment: Please mark it as solved if you believe I have fulfilled your question. Thanks, BFB :D

Comment: Thank you very much for all the time you've taken to help

Comment: Your very welcome. Best of luck with your project!!!